# Debugging C++ from Python in VS Code

Tags: python, c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug C++ shared library call from Python in VS code under linux:

the C++ code

```
extern "C" void add(const int N, const double *x,const  double *y,double *z);
void add(const int N, const double *x,const  double *y,double *z)
{
    for (int i=0;i < N;i++)  
       z[i] = x[i] + y[i];  
}
```

The Python code is:

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./pex.so")
lib.add.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int,
                    np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(np.float64),
                    np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(np.float64),
                    np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(np.float64)]

inp1 = np.random.randint(0,11,(10,7)).astype(np.float64)
inp2 = np.random.randint(0,11,(10,7)).astype(np.float64)
inp3 = np.zeros_like(inp2)
lib.add(inp1.size,inp1,inp2,inp3)
```

I have used `launch.json` according to [this](https://nadiah.org/2020/03/01/example-debug-mixed-python-c-in-visual-studio-code/) blog:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Attach",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "attach",
        "program": "/usr/bin/python",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
   
]
```

for some reason I just can't step into the `add` function. The result is OK but I can't debug the code. What am I doing wrong

Comment: "can't step into the add function" It's a bit vacuous description. What exactly are you trying to do (commands, button presses) and what VSCode reaction do you observe?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I am in the line `lib.add(inp1.size,inp1,inp2,inp3)` and pressin F11 (step into) but the debugger steps over (with the right result)

Comment: You are launching the Python debugger configuration. It cannot step into C and C++ functions. In order to debug a C or C++ function, launch the gdb configuration and set a breakpoint on your function. gdb however cannot debug python code.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. please look at https://nadiah.org/2020/03/01/example-debug-mixed-python-c-in-visual-studio-code/ I am looking for mixed debugging

Comment: Does this manual say you can step into a C function from Python with a press of a button? Yes you can run two debuggers at once, but this is far far away from cross-language debugging. The two debuggers don't talk to each other and you need to switch between them yourself. I hear VS (not VS Code) can do true cross-language debugging with Python and C/C++.